# What is "Device ID Macro" field on iOS Campaign Tracking URL Builder site?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Campaign Tracking URL Builder here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder

I select "custom" for field "Ad-Network". 
One parameter that is required is "Device ID Macro", but i can not find it anywhere in the documentation.

Where can i find "Device ID Macro" parameter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Device ID macro is the Identifier for Advertiser, normally it's %{idfa})

> What is an IDFA? The Advertising Identifier (IDFA) is a unique ID for
>   each iOS device that mobile ad networks typically use to serve
>   targeted ads. Users can choose to limit ad tracking by turning off
>   this setting on their devices.

Or in ether words:

When you do a campaign with a specialist company, you will get a idfa code to use
for tracking information on devices registered to the campaign (For example were did they come from, location etc..).

Comment: means i have to insert %{idfa} in the Device ID Macro Field ?